# Forcing iPhone Microphone as Audio Input and Bluetooth speekers as audio output

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, bluetooth

I need to take the input from iPhone/iPad/iPod default mic and buffer and pass the buffer to the bluetooth speakers.

I am done with the input buffering by using the [this example](http://ios-coreaudio-example.googlecode.com/files/Aruts.zip) and also [this example](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/), but redirecting the output to bluetooth speakers is not working.

Please help me.